# Google appengine Java SDK source code?

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, open-source

Looking for the source of some classes from the AppEngine Java SDK, namely **com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet** (mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)).

So I've downloaded http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ where I expected to find the source code of the class, instead I got zip:

```
maxim@maxim-desktop:~/Desktop/sources$ find googleappengine/ | grep -v '\.svn' | grep -v demos | grep -E '\.java$' | wc -l
0
```

What's up with that? Isn't the SDK open sourced? 
Can I download the source code from a different location?

Thanks,
Maxim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java SDK hasn't been open-sourced yet. We're working on doing so in a future release.

Comment: I see, well it's a bit misleading. Thanks for the clarification.